# Looking for a named Harry Potter character who never appears in person

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification

A group of friends of mine is doing a group Harry Potter cosplay and we're trying to work out who is going to be who to avoid clashes. I'm not going to be at the event in question, so was thinking I could "go" as a character who never actually appears in person in the books. I'm thinking someone's older brother who is off working for the entirety of the series, or something similar. People with a more encyclopaedic knowledge of Harry Potter than me, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for an un-described character? Or a character who never speaks?

Comment: Any of the Founders, Lockhart mentions several characters / creatures he has encountered, there are lots of references. This is bordering on off-topic for me though. Maybe rephrase/reframe the question to be characters mentioned but never seen

Comment: Ron's squib uncle?

Comment: I'm VTC this question as too broad. There have been many "right" answers, and I predict there will be many more.

Comment: @NKCampbell Still too broad.

Comment: Barnabus Cuff, editor of the Daily Prophet

Comment: That was Ravenclaw's daughter, Helena though. Not Rowena herself (assuming you are referencing book 7) @Jeutnarg

Comment: Apparently I'm too new to add an answer???  But I believe Neville Longbottom's parents Alice or Frank would work perfectly for what you want.  Also really like the idea of any of the Hogwarts founders (I think that's what NKCampbell was referring to)  Salazar Slytherin, Rowena Ravenclaw, Godric Gryffindor, Helga Hufflepuff.

Comment: @kasdega - the question was put on hold. Nobody can post an answer. I don't think that Neville's parents would work - we see them in OotP. And they're insane.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Couldn't you go as Charlie Weasley?**

Your cosplay group's excuse for you not being there could be, 'Oh, Charlie wanted to make it, but he's off in XX country to catch a rare glimpse of YY dragon.' etc

Comment: this works really well :)

Comment: This is a good idea but doesn't exactly fit the request because Charlie did actually show up to a number of events: The World Cup, the Triwizard Tournament, Bill and Fleur's wedding, and the Battle of Hogwarts.

Comment: Charlie appears several times throughout the series.

Answer (score 10):

**Nicholas Flamel.**

There aren't many *living* characters who are given names but never appear.  Of those, I'm guessing you want a character who has some name recognition; someone who might make people chuckle when your friends tell them why you aren't there.  For that, my recommendation is Nicholas Flamel.

Comment: But... He's dead...

Comment: was non-deadness a requirement of OP's question?

Comment: @NKCampbell - In fact, I'd think it would be a point in the character's favor. Unless the character is a ghost, being dead seems like a great excuse for not being able to attend.

Comment: Is Flamel actually dead (by the end of the deathly hallows at least)? At the end of Sorcerers Stone Dumbledore said he had enough of his potion to keep him alive long enough to get his affairs in order. I imagine after 600 years you have *a lot* of affairs to get in order.

Comment: Well he was alive during (the vast majority of) the events of the first book.  Do all of your friends plan on going as characters who survived book 7?

Comment: I believe JK confirmed that Flamel was dead by the start of Book 6 on Pottermore or something.

Answer (score 10):

## Eloise Midgen

She's mentioned a few times:

> "Well - you know," said Ron, shrugging, "I'd rather go alone than with - with Eloise Midgen, say."
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, chapter 22</sub>

She's also mentioned as having accidentally chopped her nose off, while trying to curse her pimples off.

Comment: My problem with this is that she will have been present at a lot of the events of the books, just never mentioned as such, and I'm looking for someone who's actually not present.

Answer (score 6):

You can make up a name and add a 'Weasley' surname to it, pretending to be Ron's cousin or distant relative. This is what Harry did in book 7.

Answer (score 3):

Kenneth Towler. He's a student of Fred's year who came out in boils during their OWL year because Fred put Bulbadox powder in his pajamas.

> "Kenneth Towler came out in boils, d'you remember?" "That's 'cause you
>   put Bulbadox Powder in his pajamas." "Oh yeah. I'd forgotten. . . .
>   Hard to keep track sometimes, isn't it?"

*Order of the Phoenix,* Chapter 12 *Professor Umbridge*

As for the Irish team members, you could be Aidan Lynch, who was pretty battered after the World Cup and not likely to be anywhere. Or you could be any of these known players:

Captain: Darren O'Hare (Keeper) (mid-1900s)
Captain: Aidan Lynch (Seeker) (1994)
Chaser: Troy (1994)
Chaser: Mullet (1994)
Chaser: Moran (1994)
Beater: Connolly (1994)
Beater: Quigley (1994)
Keeper: Barry Ryan (1994)

May I make two more suggestions?

1. **Gwenog Jones**- captain of the Holyhead Harpies. Appeared only once, during Slughorn's party and that was just a mention.
2. **Tom the barman from the Leaky Cauldron**- Don't see him hanging around anywhere either. He has a place to run.

Comment: It's Towler =) Good shout by the way, +1, but could you add a reference, it would really make a difference

Comment: My problem with this is that he will have been present at a lot of the events of the books, just never mentioned as such, and I'm looking for someone who's actually not present.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Perhaps you'd like to be one of the members of the Irish Quidditch team? I'll include a couple of names in case you're rusty, and I have two more suggestions. Thanks @Au101 , I'll add a quote presently and find out which chapter it is as soon as I get my book back from my little brother.

Comment: @Reya Chapter 12, *Professor Umbridge* (I edited but if you wanna change the format or whatever it's up to you. It's p. 205 of the original Bloomsbury edition, but I don't know what edition you use

Comment: @Au101 It is a Bloomsbury edition so I suppose it's just about the same. Thank you :)

Comment: @naverag - Yet you accepted Charlie.